# Automatic PHP asset compilation & caching with git, heroku

Tags: php, git, cakephp, heroku, githooks

I have some assets (ie, JS, CSS) that I need to compile for my CakePHP app hosted on Heroku utilizing [AssetCompress](https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress).  I'd like to automate the compilation process so that the files are cached and ready to be loaded by the user.  Since these are ephemeral cache files, it seems like the ideal place to do this would be on Heroku once it receives the push (as opposed to committed into the git repo), but I can't seem to find a way to do that.

So, what's the simplest way I can automate this compilation/caching process to save myself having to do it manually every time I need to push changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate way to customize and prepare the runtime environment of a Heroku app is to [create a custom buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks), particularly in regards to the compile script.  This feature is available on the cedar stack.

Comment: github repo seems to be private or deleted

Comment: We're no longer using that buildpack, you can still check out the documentation and customize [heroku's PHP builpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php) to meet your needs.